# Does Windows 8 still implement POSIX?

Tags: windows-8, sua

I have a few piece of junk homemade programs that use the Windows POSIX sublayer. Does Windows 8 x64 come with SUA?

Can somebody verify that it is there? All I can find is that it was "deprecated" but the news seems to be from a year or two back.

Comment: Use a comment to comment, not an edit to the question.

Comment: @ChrisF I want my tag and I want it now! My goal is to go down in history as the only user of Windows SUA :-)

Comment: Tag created, Wiki Excerpt created - you should go fill up the tag wiki. Remember not to copy it wholesale from somewhere and such.

Comment: Bob is a cool dude, but may be somebody has tried running software on it and something terrible happens. I am actually install the server to try to see if my "junk" still runs on it. Give me an hour or two.

Comment: @Misha but you should still be happy to know that you can still run your junk in Win 8 (atleast until the next security update where they remove it altogether, Good luck for then!).

Comment: @LincolnBergeson I don't think any one gonna to answer this as it has an answer accepted already. What extra do you need can you clarify?

Comment: I have Windows 8 Pro, I does not even have that SUA . Where did you get it from, any other way to run POSIX programs on windows 8?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

In the Enterprise Evaluation (essentially, a trial version of Windows 8 Enterprise RTM), [SUA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Services_for_UNIX#Subsystem_for_UNIX-based_Applications_.28SUA.29) is still available through Windows Features, though listed as deprecated:

[[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk27X.png)

Comment: I like what you did there with the image and the proof.

Comment: It isn't listed as a deprecated feature on the [aforementioned link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=217355).

Comment: @EvanCarroll That link appears to be broken - it's talking about deprecated features for Windows 8 and Server 2008 R2. [This one](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831568.aspx) dealing with Server 2012 is closer, but it basically repeats the rest of the text in that tooltip...

Comment: Ah clearly this is either (a) photo-shopped, or (b) Windows 8 isn't ready for prime time and should be recalled en masse. Seriously, who puts out a product with buggy link-references. Microsoft can't event tell its users to RTFM properly.

Comment: By "alternate methods" presumably they mean Cygwin or MinGW, which are both perfectly reasonable means of getting a reasoanble POSIXy interface that sits on top of Win32 as opposed to trying to use SUA, which IIRC were never really all that complete to begin with anyway.

Comment: @fluffy, just one problem. cygwin does not install on Win8.1.  Chocolatey did not help to install it either.

Comment: @rjt Ah, that's unfortunate.

Answer (score 17):

[Wikipedia states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Services_for_UNIX#Subsystem_for_UNIX-based_Applications_.28SUA.29) that it is deprecated in Windows 8 and will be removed in Windows 8.1.

> WARNING: SUA is deprecated starting with this release and will be completely removed in the next release.

Comment: In theory it could be removed in the first Service Pack, we don't know if there will be a typical Windows 9, evidence points to Microsoft changing their release schedule.  Visual Studio and other products are already on slightly difference schedules then in the past.

Answer (score 9):

SUA is being removed from Windows kernel. It shows as `DEPRECATED` which means this is probably the last version of windows which will support it.

Here is a `link` that suggests so.
http://blogs.technet.com/b/sfu/archive/2011/10/03/installing-sua-components-on-windows-8.aspx

Answer (score 8):

SUA is only available in Windows 8 with "premium" client SKUs (meaning Ultimate or Enterprise) or server SKUs (meaning Windows Server 2012). (More info in [source](http://brianreiter.org/2011/09/15/sua-deprecated-in-windows-8/).)

SUA is not available in your version of Windows 8 Professional.

You should look for alternatives such as [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/).
A commercial alternative is [MKS Toolkit](http://www.mkssoftware.com/products/tk/ds_tkdev.asp)

Comment: I actually expected this reply to be incorrect, but checked on my one (so far) RTM Windows Pro install, and it is in fact correct.  SUA is no longer shipped with Windows 8 Pro.

Comment: @harrymc, cygwin does  not install on Win8.1

Comment: @rjt: I think this is solved in the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

**2016 Windows Subsystem for Linux Update**

I don't think this will affect Windows 8, but it might be interesting for newer releases.

In 2016 a new official Linux-like API called "Windows Subsystem for Linux" was announced. It includes Linux system calls, ELF running, parts of the /proc filesystem, Bash, GCC, (TODO likely glibc?), apt-get and more: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/P488 so I believe that it will allow Windows to run much, if not all, of POSIX. However, it is focused on developers / deployment instead of end users. In particular, there were no plans to allow access to the Windows GUI.